# Oracle SQL Developer не запускается

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

При запуске SQL Developer 18.2, появляется окно со статусом загрузки, доходит до Restoring Windows и все. После удаления файлов c:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system18.2.0.183.1748\, первый раз запускается, а потом опять тоже самое - не загружается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]